# Multi-step registration and security

Tags: security, registration

Assume we have a registration process in multiple steps:

1. Initial form asks for some information (first and last names, id number, phone number, email address)
2. After the form is submitted, the second step consists of verifying the phone number by sending a code that needs to be entered next
3. Then, we need to verify the id number using credit card.

My question is:

Should we create an account just after the initial form is submitted? Or should we create the account at the end when all steps are successful?

If I go with second solution, it implies that the information is kept in a temporary registration session until the end of the process where all the information is passed to some API to create the account.

What are the best practices?

Comment: This depends on your requirement! In general scenario, the first option is preferred, IMO.

Comment: I thought a lot about first option, it complicates things. I like the idea that a registration is a process where all data is kept in a temporary session that is saved at the end. If you know about security issues with the second option...